# CSV counting duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, date, csv, datetime, counter

I've got a csv file which has a column of dates with year, month, day, hour. I'm trying to create a new csv file with one column of all the dates between the max and min from from the first file, and a second column with a count of the number of times that date appears. For example:

```
file 1:
2016-02-18-23:19
2016-02-18-23:45
2016-01-03-05:12
2016-01-03-07:57
```

would become

```
file2:
2016-01-03-05    1
2016-01-03-06    0
2016-01-03-07    1
...
2016-02-18-22    0
2016-02-18-23    2
```

I can pull the dates and make a dictionary of the dates and their occurrence using counter, I'm guessing I'll have to use datetime to create a list from max to min in the dictionary by hour, then somehow assign the counts to a second list. This would be for a very large data set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the pandas solution.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                            
df=pd.read_csv("file1",sep=":",names=['v'])                                                                                                                                                    
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)                                                                                                                                                              
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('H')).size().to_csv("file2")
```

The output file will look like this,

```
2016-01-03 05:00:00,1
2016-01-03 06:00:00,0
2016-01-03 07:00:00,1
2016-01-03 08:00:00,0
...
2016-02-18 19:00:00,0
2016-02-18 20:00:00,0
2016-02-18 21:00:00,0
2016-02-18 22:00:00,0
2016-02-18 23:00:00,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just going by the tags you've associated with your question, I am providing a solution that uses `Counter`, `datetime` and good ol' `csv`:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime
import csv


with open('file2.txt','w') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = "\t", lineterminator = "\n")
    data = Counter([datetime.strptime(x.strip(),'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H') for x in open('file1.txt')]).items()
    data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x[0])
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

This yields a file with the following content:

```
2016-01-03-05   1
2016-01-03-07   1
2016-02-18-23   2
```

#### Edit:

On second thought, I think I may have misunderstood the question a bit. It does seem to me that you are looking to have some dates missing from the original added to the output file with their counts being zero. I think the following should be a bit more encompassing:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv


with open('file2.txt','w') as outfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = "\t", lineterminator = "\n")

    # Get each row and convert it to datetime
    # Get the minimum and maximum values
    datetimes = [datetime.strptime(x.strip(),'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M') for x in open('file1.txt')]
    min_date = min(datetimes)

    # Get the number of hours between min and max dates
    num_hours = (max(datetimes) - min_date).seconds//3600 + 24 * (max(datetimes) - min_date).days

    # Convert to desired date format
    datetimes = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H') for x in datetimes]

    # Count the values
    data = Counter(datetimes).items()

    # Add the mising days from the original file
    for i in range(num_hours):
        if (min_date + timedelta(hours = i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H') not in datetimes:
            data.append(((min_date + timedelta(hours = i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H'), 0))

    # Sort by dates
    data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: x[0])

    # Output the data into file2.txt
    csv_writer.writerows(data)
```

This one should yield:

```
2016-01-03-05   1
2016-01-03-06   0
2016-01-03-07   1
2016-01-03-08   0
2016-01-03-09   0
2016-01-03-10   0
...
2016-02-18-21   0
2016-02-18-22   0
2016-02-18-23   2
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Almost, the second code you wrote added the missing dates, but only for 05:00. I'm trying to get it to fill out all the hours for all the dates. I'd have to change

    num_days = (max(datetimes) - min_date).days

to hours instead I think.

Comment: @JoshuaKidd, yea changing the interval to number of hours is the key here. Please see my edits. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a regex:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}$')
stamps = {}

with open('file1.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.read().splitlines()

for line in lines:
    if regex.search(line):
        elements = line.split('-')
        elements.extend(elements.pop().split(':'))
        key = elements[0] + '-' + elements[1] + '-' + elements[2] + '-' + elements[3]
        stamps.setdefault(key, 0)
        stamps[key] += 1

with open('file2.csv','w') as output_file:
    for key, value in sorted(stamps.items()):
        output_file.write(key + '\t' + str(value) + '\n')
```

*file1.csv*

```
2016-02-18-23:19
2016-02-18-23:45
2016-01-03-05:12
2016-01-03-07:57
```

*file2.csv*

```
2016-01-03-05 1
2016-01-03-07 1
2016-02-18-23 2
```